# Удалить из строки все лишнее

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть прайс в формате scv, где цены указаны очень криво: в некоторых местах целые и дробные разряды разделены точкой, в некоторых - запятой, а в некоторых перед числом еще и мусор какой-то из букв и кракозябр. Я пытаюсь заменить при помощи preg_replace() (php) весь нечисловой мусор на пустую строку, а запятую на точку, но в регекспах я нуб и нифига не выходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, примеры строк с которыми Вы работаете и ожидаемый результат после обработки этих строк. Так будет легче Вам подсказать.

Comment: 2ï¾ 388,66 -> 388.66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заменить запятые на точки. В результате запятых больше нет.
2. `"[^0-9.]+"` - выборка очередной порции нечисловых символов.

команда

`php -r "echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', 'adasd098xxx.098RRRR');"`

выдаст:

`098.098`

Comment: тогда уж так
`php -r "echo preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]+/', '', str_replace(',','.','adasd098xxx,098RRRR'));"`

Comment: Спасибо! В какой-то момент до меня дошло, что крякозябры - это неразрывный пробел, разделяющий разряды и превратившийся при конвертации майкросовтским эксэлем в .csv, в нечто потусторонее. Ваш пример сделал то, что нужно: 2ï¾ 388,66 -> 2388.66